# Python Bubble Sort list with swap count

Tags: python, sorting

I'm trying to make a function that sorts a list using bubble sorting and returns a tuple with the number of swaps and comparisons. Such that:

```
print(perform_bubble_sort([3, 5, 7]))    
>>> (3, 0)
```

.
I tried using the following code but it doesn't return the right number of comparisons for some reason.

```
def perform_bubble_sort(blist):
    cmpcount, swapcount = 0, 0
    while True:
        swapped = False
        for i in range(1, len(blist)):
            cmpcount += 1
            if blist[i-1] > blist[i]:
                swapcount += 1
                blist[i-1], blist[i] = blist[i], blist[i-1]
                swapped = True
        if not swapped:
            break
    return cmpcount, swapcount
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
def perform_bubble_sort(blist):
    cmpcount, swapcount = 0, 0
    for j in range(len(blist)):
        for i in range(1, len(blist)-j):
            cmpcount += 1
            if blist[i-1] > blist[i]:
                swapcount += 1
                blist[i-1], blist[i] = blist[i], blist[i-1]
    return cmpcount, swapcount
```

You don't need to iterate over `blist` every time

Comment: That works! How would I get this function to stop executing when all the items are sorted?

Comment: @Newbie You can use `swapped` like that. I remove it because usually people don't do that in bubble sort.

Answer (score 0):

```
def queue(lst):
    n = len(lst)
    swipe_count = 0

    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n - i - 1):
            if lst[j] > lst[j + 1]:
                lst[j], lst[j + 1] = lst[j + 1], lst[j]
                swipe_count += 1

    return lst, swipe_count
```